# sharpdx tkfxc.exe generates .tkb file when .tkfxo expected

Tags: c++, sharpdx

I'm facing a problem and I couldn't find any documentation at all. Also I downloaded the github `sharpdx` solution but I didn't found an answer.

When I'm executing `tkfxc.exe` in `net40` directory, the `.fx` effect compiles successfully but as I read on many forums, a `.tkfxo` file shall be generated. Instead of that I got a `.tkb` file.

This is the command line command I'm using:

```
tkfxc.exe /FoInverted.tkfxo Inverted.fx
```

Even if I try to change the extension to the file or just load this file as a filter, sharpDX said that is invalid file, some other `CHUNK` expected.